# Show hyper targets in resulting document

Tags: hyperref

The `showlabels` package can show labels (made with `\label`) in the margin of the resulting document (simply by loading the package). I'm looking for similar functionality but for `\hypertarget` (from the `hyperref` package). That is, I want every hyper target in a document to be shown. I'm asking for this to ease development of documents with hyper targets.

It would also be nice to be able to show every `\hyperlink` in the margin (I know that this can be done by decorating links).

---

To illustrate what I want let me compare the functionality of showlabels to what I want. The following example puts the names of labels in the margin:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showlabels}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\label{text}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Label's name is shown in the margin]

What I'm asking for is a way to put the name of hyper targets in the margin. If "text" is the name of a hyper target what I'm asking for is for something like the following code to produce a result like the image above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showhypertargets}% This is just an example, this package does not exist

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{text}{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following answer may surprise you:

```
\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\showlabels{hypertarget}
```